# Optimize concatenation in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia

I have a very simple function written in Julia that needs to be run millions of times.

Code:

```
function randfunc()
  #rands could be a global variable if desired
  rands = rand(200,100000)
  for i=1:100000
    #the alphabet can continue (and in Q1 as well)
    # rand(1:100000) generates a random number within the number of columns in rands
    a = rand(1:100000) 
    b = rand(1:100000)
    c = rand(1:100000)
    d = rand(1:100000)
    e = rand(1:100000)
    Q1 = hcat(rands[:,a],rands[:,b],rands[:,c],rands[:,d],rands[:,e])
    Q2 = *(Q1.',Q1)
  end
end
```

Is there any way to speed up the hcat function or replace it with something more efficient?

Another way to speed up this function would be to manually do the matrix multiplication without constructing the Q1 matrix, but the built-in `*(,)` operator runs faster than using `+`'s and `*`'s, at least on my attempt, and doing this seems to have more overhead than simply constructing Q1.

Using `rands = convert(Array{Float32}, rands)` helps a bit, but `Float16` is actually worse (especially for matrix multiplication). The elements in `rands` cannot be strictly integers, and the number of column vectors is arbitrary in Q1.

Edit: The initial concept of this question was to try to obtain a quick way of calling a matrix from data that would later be part of a matrix multiplication with its transpose. I have edited the code to try to address any ambiguity.

Old Code:

```
function randfunc()
  #rands could be a global variable if desired
  rands = rand(200,100000)
  for i=1:100000-1
    Q1 = hcat(rands[:,[i]],rands[:,[i]].*rands[:,[i+1]])
    Q2 = *(Q1.',Q1)
  end
end
```

Comment: What does the function return? (it seems to be nothing)

Comment: I cut off the code because everything after that was pretty well optimized. If you need the function to return something, you can have it return det(Q2).

Comment: Which `Q2`? There are `100000-1` different `Q2` calculated in the loop?

Comment: All of them. The `Q2`s can be written into a pre-allocated vector.

Comment: Posted an answer below. If you verify the correctness of the calculated values it would be nice to know.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the slow version of the function you want to optimize (arbitrary Q1 columns and all). A verbal description is often ambiguous (e.g. how should the additional columns in Q1 be generated from `rands`)

Comment: i) Can you also fix the return value of the function (use `det(Q2)` if necessary), as this way the function can be optimized by `randfunc() = nothing`. ii) Note the older code is in no way a special case of the new code (second column is in fixed offset and is multiplied with first). iii) Is there some reason not to simply state the actual calculation required?

Comment: I must say I am thoroughly confused by this code, but I want to make two observations: Firstly, `rands[:, [a, b, c, d, e]]` is _much_ faster than `hcat(rands[:, a], rands[:, b], rands[:, c], rands[:, d], rands[:, e])`, and, secondly, `*(,)` is _not_ faster than `*`, they are exactly the same thing, so it is better to use `*` in the infix position for readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code tries to optimize the function by simplifying the calculation into two nested `for` loops. Basically, this calculates the same expression the original matrix form does, by expanding the expressions in terms of the input `rands` matrix elements. The return value is a vector of the determinants of the `Q2` matrices.

```
function randfunc2(rands)
  a,b,c = 0.0,0.0,0.0
  detvec = Vector{Float64}(size(rands,2)-1)
  @inbounds for i=1:(size(rands,2)-1)
    a,b,c = 0.0,0.0,0.0
    @inbounds for j=1:size(rands,1)
      s = rands[j,i]
      t = s*s
      u = s*rands[j,i+1]
      a += t
      b += s*u
      c += u*u
    end
    detvec[i] = a*c-b*b    # calc determinant using 2x2 det formula
    # Q2 = [a b; b c]
  end
  return detvec
end
```

To use this function, as in the example in the question:

```
rands = rand(200,100000)
randfunc2(rands)        # this returns the determinant vectors.
```

The allocations are very minimal and each matrix element is accessed twice but in column order (which is the fast order).

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that the number of concatenated column vectors is arbitrary. However, I might still use the ideas in this answer as the code runs super fast (and is correct).

Answer (score 3):

Breaking your code into smaller pieces + using views helped bring down allocations about 60%:

```
function randfunc()
    #rands could be a global variable if desired
    n=100000
    rands = rand(200,n)
    for i=1:n-1
        Q1 = hcat(rands[:,[i]],rands[:,[i]].*rands[:,[i+1]])
        Q2 = *(Q1.',Q1)
    end
end

function Q1(r1,r2)
   hcat(r1,r1.*r2) 
end
function some_mult(Q)
    *(Q',Q)
end
function randfunc2()
    n=100000
    #rands could be a global variable if desired
    rands = rand(200,n)
    for i=1:n-1
        Q2 = some_mult(Q1(
            view(rands,:,[i]),
            view(rands,:,[i+1])))
    end
end
@time randfunc()  #1.883301 seconds (3.20 M allocations: 1.228 GB, 30.84% gc time)
@time randfunc2() #1.656203 seconds (2.90 M allocations: 736.978 MB, 31.27% gc time)
```